# How to run a Python script on a raspberry pi via webserver?

Tags: raspbian, python, raspicam, apache-httpd, lxterminal

Hi everyone I am trying to run a python script on my raspberry pi 2 via web server running apache2, php, and raspbian jessie. What my plan is to do is have a timelapse camera using python (code below) and when I go to a webpage it and click a button and it will start to run the script below.

```
import time
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from subprocess import call
from datetime import datetime
import math
import os


green = 16 #Running 
red = 20 #wating for sunset
startBut = 21 #button to start every thing


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(startBut, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP) #push button
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)


d = datetime.now()
initYear = "%04d" % (d.year) 
initMonth = "%02d" % (d.month) 
initDate = "%02d" % (d.day)
initSec = "%02s" % (d.second)
initMin = "%02s" % (d.minute)

folderToSave = "/media/TIMELAPS/timelapse_" + str(initYear) + "_" + str(initMonth) + "_" +  str(initDate) + "_" + str(initMin) + "_" + str(initSec) + "/"
#folderToSave2 = "timelapse_" + str(initYear) + "_" + str(initMonth) + "_" +  str(initDate) + "_" + str(initSec) + "/"
os.mkdir(folderToSave)
#GPIO.wait_for_edge(startBut, GPIO.FALLING)
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    #GPIO.output(green, GPIO.HIGH)
    var = 1
    fileNum = 0
    while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop
        if fileNum <= 9:
            fileName = "0" + str(fileNum)
            print("file name = " + fileName)
        else:
            fileName = "" + str(fileNum)
            print("file name = " + fileName)


        camera.capture(folderToSave + fileName + ".jpg") #takes the photo to the flashdrive
        #camera.capture(folderToSave2 + fileName) #takes the photo and saves to the apple timecaplse disk
        fileNum = fileNum + 1



        time.sleep(5)
    print("Good Bye")
```

and here is my Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Raspbery Pi Timelapse camera</title>
    <script>
        function runPythonScript(file) {
            if (file == "time") {
            //run the Time_laps_camera.py  
            }
            else if (file == "aperture") {
            //run the pi_camera_aperture.py
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <div style="padding: 20px 10px;" ></div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="runPythonScript('time')">TimeLapse Camera</button>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 15px;">
        <button type="button" onclick="runPythonScript('aperture')">TimeLapse Camera</button>
    </div>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

So basicly what I am trying to do is insted of me connecting to my pi via remote desktop and executing the script what I want to do is want to go to a webpage and hit a button and run the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CGI script - this basically means you can get scripts run by the webserver. Here are some samples from a old project I did *(not necessarily the best way of doing stuff, but it worked quite well if with some latency over a WiFi connection)*:

**controls-touchembed.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Robox Pi - Controls</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"
<meta id="author" content="Wilf" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1252" >
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: url("texture.png");
  }

  #fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  #arrowPad {
   border: 1px #E5E5E5;
    }

  #arrowPadCell {
   border: 1px #E5E5E5;
   background-image: url(arrowpad4/bg.png);
    }

  #arrowPadCell.h {
   border: 1px #E5E5E5;
   background-image: url(arrowpad4/bg.png);
    }

  #arrowPadCell.h:hover {
   border: 1px #E5E5E5;
   background-image: url(arrowpad4/bg2.png);
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="fixed">
      <table id="arrowPad">
            <tr>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" style="-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-left-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;"></td>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" class="h"><a href="/cgi-bin/forward.cgi" ><img src="arrowpad4/2.png" id="a2" alt="Forward"></img></a></td>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" style="-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" class="h"><a href="/cgi-bin/left.cgi" ><img src="arrowpad4/4.png" id="a4" alt="Left"></img></a></td>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" class="h"><a href="/cgi-bin/clear.cgi" ><img src="arrowpad4/5.png" id="a5" alt="Stop"></img></a></td>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" class="h"><a href="/cgi-bin/right.cgi" ><img src="arrowpad4/6.png" id="a6" alt="Right"></img></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" style="-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;"></td>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" class="h"><a href="/cgi-bin/backward.cgi" ><img src="arrowpad4/8.png" id="a8" alt="Backward"></img></a></td>
            <td id="arrowPadCell" style="-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;"></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
</html>
```

**cgi-bin/forward.cgi**

```
#!/bin/bash

forward

echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
```

This I think I did following [this guide](http://raspberrywebserver.com/gpio/piface/building-a-remote-control-vehicle-using-a-raspberry-pi.html). My script above was used to invoke commands that are the `$PATH`, which were python scripts that used GPIOs to control motors etc. Note with some apache server setups, you may need so setup the security for a directory to have the CGI scripts in - this often is `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`, `/var/www/cgi-bin`, etc.

I haven't done this using python scripts directly (I think CGI scripts can various languages, but you need to define [the shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) on the first line)). There is also is a python module as well (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts))